# Translating (WooCommerce) placeholder text

Tags: customization, plugins

So, as the title says, I'm trying to translate the output text of WooCommcerce on the "Cart" and "Checkout" pages, it currently says "select a state" where I want "select a province".

I was not able to accomplish this with filters & hooks, as it's something they have overlooked. I was hoping somebody here can help me figure out how to translate the text so it displays as I want. I don't mind if this is using a plugin, native wordpress functionality or whatever, as long as I get it done.

[The site in question can be found here.](http://seekoften.com/eCommerce/checkout)

Thanks in advance, hopefully you guys and gals can give me a hand with this :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `gettext`:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translation, $text, $domain ) 
{
    if ( 'woocommerce' === $domain and 'Select a state&hellip;' === $text )
        return 'Select a province&hellip;';

    return $translation;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Note the `3` as last parameter. This ensures you get all three variables passed, so you can replace exactly the text you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I appreciate it tons, I've had so much trouble getting help with this 

However, I added it to my functions.php (child theme), and it broke the site.... any idea why ?

Comment: Your PHP version is probably completely out of date. PHP 5.3 has reached its end of life already. Your are using PHP 5.2 which lacks [some important security fixes](http://www.cvedetails.com/version/106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html). You should update to at least PHP 5.4.

Comment: Now this might sound kind of stupid, but how do I upgrade my PHP ?

Comment: That’s usually a setting in your web host back-end.

Comment: MY NINJA!!!!!

Thank you so much. This was exactly what I needed. You're my hero tonight, dude. 

I updated the version to 5.4 and it works perfectly. I searched high & wide for this, and never found an answer so concise or effective. I spent literally 2 full days of work looking for this fix.